# Combining Apache ServerAlias and 301 Redirects

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect, serveralias

I've referenced [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/281883/301-redirect-or-serveralias-for-multiple-tlds) but I'm not sure if I'm clear on how this works given this situation:

I have a client with two brands that are currently online like this:

```
Brand A (site 1)    Brand B (site 2)
---                 ---  
site 1 pages        site 2 pages
```

Now, they've had a new site built that combines content from both sites and unifies their two brands into one:

```
Brand Unified (site 3)
---
site 3 pages
```

Clearly there are 301 redirects I want to put into place for each original site after I update the A records for each domain. However, the new site is a custom WordPress theme and WP only allows for one domain per installation. This leaves me with a situation where I can assign the original TLD from, say, Brand A as the site URL in WordPress, and then have the Brand B domain redirect to A.

I thought I would use a server block like this in the Apache site conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com  #site1.com now points directly here
    ServerAlias site2.com #site2.com points directly but redirects
    ServerAdmin admin@brandAsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite
```

So, assuming there is nothing wrong with this configuration, what happens if I try to implement 301 redirects for site1 and site2 links? Specifically, since site2.com is now listed as an alias of site1.com, can I still effectively have 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` file in the `/var/www/newsite/` directory or does ServerAlias interfere with that? I'm wondering if it gets aliased to back to site1.com and therefore the 301 rules wouldn't trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to configure Apache conf, why complicate situation and put redirects (or anything) in `.htaccess` files? You seem to assign site2.com to /var/www/newsite only for the purpose to using `.htaccess` and nothing else. I would keep it simple, everything in one place:

```
NameVirtualHost  *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com

    # Specifically mapped redirects
    Redirect permanent /foo/ http://site1.com/new-foo/

    # Root redirect (if no other cases above match)
    Redirect permanent /  http://site1.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The URL structure on the new site is different than the old site - doesn't this solution throw away the ability to do specific mapping of old URLs to new ones?

Comment: I didn't catch the requirement "to do specific mapping of old URLs to new ones". My answer doesn't fulfill it.

Comment: Feel free to update if you do know the answer! Thanks for taking the time in the first place.

Comment: Can I place all of my 301s in that second block? Or does the forwarding of `/` trump them all and simply redirect any traffic from the old domain to the new one?

Comment: @armadadrive I believe you can put specific redirects before the general `/` one.

Comment: `Redirect permanent / http://example.com/` **Trailing slash are required**, otherwise `http://oldsite.example.com/asdf` redirects to `http://example.comasdf`